# Ansible and jenkins integration

Tags: jenkins, ansible

Is it mandatory to have jenkins and Ansible to be installed on Same Server?
I have Jenkins server installed on windows and ansible installed on Linux machine ,how to integrate Anisble and Jenkins?

Comment: You need to describe what you want to do with Ansible. 
While Ansible can manage Windows hosts it cannot run on Windows hosts.

Comment: You can specify the Linux instance as a Jenkins build agent with a specific label and execute your Ansible from there. As a corollary, you could use a Docker agent with Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

*Jenkins can use your Linux's Machine*

On Jenkins's projet, *use Script Shell*:

Use this command to run your playbook

```
ssh $USER@$LUNIX_IP -p $LUNIX_PORT -o "ForwardAgent=yes" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=1 ansible-playbook $PLAYBOOK -i $HOST
```